# How to extract year and week number in a dataframe and put it in a new column, python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe :

```
sale_id      created_at
1               2016-05-28T05:53:31.042Z
2               2016-05-30T12:50:58.184Z
3               2016-05-23T10:22:18.858Z
4               2016-05-27T09:20:15.158Z
5               2016-05-21T08:30:17.337Z
6               2016-05-28T07:41:14.361Z
```

i need t add a year-week columns where it contains year and week number of each row in created_at column:

```
sale_id      created_at                      year_week
1               2016-05-28T05:53:31.042Z       2016-21
2               2016-05-30T12:50:58.184Z       2016-22
3               2016-05-23T10:22:18.858Z       2016-21
4               2016-05-27T09:20:15.158Z       2016-21
5               2016-05-21T08:30:17.337Z       2016-20
6               2016-05-28T07:41:14.361Z       2016-21
```

I'd prefer a solution that can be easily transferred to pyspark as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

[Python's strftime directives](http://strftime.org/).

```
#if dtype is not datetime
df.created_at = pd.to_datetime(df.created_at)

df['year_week'] = df.created_at.dt.strftime('%Y-%U')
print (df)
   sale_id              created_at year_week
0        1 2016-05-28 05:53:31.042   2016-21
1        2 2016-05-30 12:50:58.184   2016-22
2        3 2016-05-23 10:22:18.858   2016-21
3        4 2016-05-27 09:20:15.158   2016-21
4        5 2016-05-21 08:30:17.337   2016-20
5        6 2016-05-28 07:41:14.361   2016-21
```

Another solution with [`dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) and [`dt.week`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.week.html):

```
df['year_week'] = df.created_at.dt.year.astype(str) + '-' +
                  df.created_at.dt.week.astype(str)
print (df)
   sale_id              created_at year_week
0        1 2016-05-28 05:53:31.042   2016-21
1        2 2016-05-30 12:50:58.184   2016-22
2        3 2016-05-23 10:22:18.858   2016-21
3        4 2016-05-27 09:20:15.158   2016-21
4        5 2016-05-21 08:30:17.337   2016-20
5        6 2016-05-28 07:41:14.361   2016-21
```

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE:** PySpark DF solution:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn('year_week', df.select(date_format('created_at', 'yyyy-w'))
```

**Old Pandas solution:**

try this:

```
df['year_week'] = df.created_at.dt.year.astype(str) + '-' + df.created_at.dt.weekofyear.astype(str)

In [29]: df
Out[29]:
   sale_id              created_at year_week
0        1 2016-05-28 05:53:31.042   2016-21
1        2 2016-05-30 12:50:58.184   2016-22
2        3 2016-05-23 10:22:18.858   2016-21
3        4 2016-05-27 09:20:15.158   2016-21
4        5 2016-05-21 08:30:17.337   2016-20
5        6 2016-05-28 07:41:14.361   2016-21
```

**Timing against 600K rows DF:**

```
In [33]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)

In [34]: %timeit df.created_at.dt.strftime('%Y-%U')
1 loop, best of 3: 16.1 s per loop

In [35]: %timeit df.created_at.dt.year.astype(str) + '-' + df.created_at.dt.weekofyear.astype(str)
1 loop, best of 3: 7.43 s per loop

In [43]: %timeit df.created_at.dt.year.astype(str) + '-' + df.created_at.dt.week.astype(str)
1 loop, best of 3: 7.45 s per loop

In [36]: df.shape
Out[36]: (600000, 2)
```